# Split strings that have strange pattern

Tags: c#

I need help to split a collection of strings that have rather strange pattern.

Example data:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("Blue Code \n 03 ID \n 05 Example \n Sky is blue");
input.Add("Green Code\n 01 ID\n 15");
input.Add("Test TestCode \n 99 \n Testing is fun");
```

Expected output:

```
For input[0]:
string part1 = "Blue"
string part2 = "Code \n 03"
string part3 = "ID \n 05"
string part4 = "Example \n Sky is blue"

For input[1]:
string part1 = "Green"
string part2 = "Code\n 01"
string part3 = "ID\n 15"

For input[2]:
string part1 = "Test"
string part2 = "TestCode \n 99"
string part3 = "\n Testing is fun"
```

> > Edited with one more example:

```
"038  038\n 0004  049.0\n 0006"
```

Expected output:

```
"038"
"038\n 0004"
"049.0\n 0006"
```

In short, I don't even know how to describe the pattern... It seems like I need the first string(act as a key) right before the "\n" as part of the new string, but the last input[2] has slightly different pattern from the other 2. Also, please **take note of the spaces**, they are extremely inconsistent.

I know this is a long shot, but please let me know if anyone can figure out how to deal with these data.

> > **Updated:** I think I can forget about solving this... When I actually take a look at the database in detail, I just found out that there are NOT only \n, it can be... anything, including |a |b |c (from a-z, A-Z), \a \b \c (from a-z, A-Z). Manually re-entering the data could be much more easier...

Comment: you can't describe the pattern because there is no pattern.why don't you store your values in an appropriate format ? like csv (comma-separated values) ?

Comment: I'm working on a legacy database from the 1960s, the original data come as one huge string like "Blue Code \n 03 ID \n 05 Example \n Sky is blue \n something something \n something something \n more thing"

Comment: @Selman22 He may be working with legacy data and cannot change it?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the pattern is to take the first word out and then split right after a number char is found, unless the following char is also a number?

Comment: @Crono No, I checked the database, there are numbers before the \n

Comment: Is there is a bit more syntactic meaning to each section than is initially apparent, it _might_ be possible to construct a `Regex` for this, but on first glance I'm not sure even that is possible.

Comment: Are all the others similar to these 3 examples?

Comment: Then I'm sorry but you'll have to make the pattern clearer before you can get any decent help.

Comment: Is it possible to have as many different possible outputs?
Are there column names associated with this output?
Are the columns length delimited or delimited in any way?

Comment: @ChrisBallard Yes, at least they are similar to the 3 patterns I listed above, with an addition that number can appear before the "\n"

Comment: Okay so there sometimes are numbers before a "/n". Then what would be the expected splitted result in this case? Add an example to your post.

Comment: @RichardPriddy Currently no, but that's exactly what I need to do - parse the data and put them into the "real" database

Comment: Ok, so there is no delimiter at all? The "columns" could be any length. Some "columns" could be blank, thus not appear? Can we please have some more data in your example outputs to try and discover some pattern?

Comment: Aside from when followed by \n is there any other cases where strings aren't splitted after numeric chars?

Comment: @RichardPriddy I only need to split when there is a presence of \n, the difference is, sometimes the data can be "key \n value", sometimes it is just "\n value" with no key

Comment: @Crono the "key" can both be string or numeric,  and "value" can be both string or numeric as well

Answer (score 0):

I would say the pattern is:

```
List<string> input = new List<string>();
input.Add("Blue Code \n 03 ID \n 05 Example \n Sky is blue");
input.Add("Green Code\n 01 ID\n 15");
input.Add("Test TestCode \n 99 \n Testing is fun");

foreach(string text in  input)
{
    string rest = text;
    //1 Take first word
    string part1 = rest.Split(' ')[0];
    rest = rest.Skip(part1.Length).ToString();
    //while rest contains (/n number)

    while (rest.Contains("\n"))
    {
        //Take until /n number
        int index = rest.IndexOf("\n");
        string partNa = rest.Take(index).ToString();
        string temp = rest.Skip(index).ToString();
        string partNb = temp.Split(' ')[0];
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse("123", out n))
        {
            string partN = partNa + partNb;
            rest = rest.Skip(partN.Length).ToString();
        }
    }

    //Take rest
    string part3 = rest;
}
```

It could probably be written a bit more optimised, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have got this little code snippet to generate the output you are looking for. the Pattern seems to be: Word [Key \n Value] [Key \n Value] [Key \n Value (With Spaces)]
Where the Key can be empty. Is that right?

```
        var input = new List<string>
        {
            "Blue Code \n 03 ID \n 05 Example \n Sky is blue",
            "Green Code\n 01 ID\n 15",
            "038  038\n 0004  049.0\n 0006",
            "Test TestCode \n 99 \n Testing is fun"
        };

        var output = new List<List<string>>();
        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            var items = new List<string> {item.Split(' ')[0]};

            const string strRegex = @"(?<group>[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*\s*\n\s*[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)";
            var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);

            var matchCollection = myRegex.Matches(item.Remove(0, item.Split(' ')[0].Length));

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if (matchCollection[i].Success)
                {
                    items.Add(matchCollection[i].Value);
                }
            }

            var index = item.IndexOf(items.Last()) + items.Last().Length;

            var final = item.Substring(index);

            if (final.Contains("\n"))
            {
                items.Add(final);
            }
            else
            {
                items[items.Count -1 ] = items[items.Count - 1] + final;
            }

            output.Add(items);
        }
```